# How can i pass an attribute to a javascript function by reference?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I want to manipulate some attributes of my page elements in a java script function , take a look at this example and maybe you find a solution to do this.

```
function doubleup(attr){
attr*=2;
}
doubleup(myDIV.style.zIndex);
doubleup(myDIV.style.opacity);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you don't. You can't pass *primitive* values by reference.
You can do that with non-primitive values, though, as they're always passed as reference. Example:

```
function doubleup(object, property) {
    object[propety] *= 2;
}
doubleup(myDiv.style, "zIndex");
doubleup(myDiv.style, "opacity");
```

Primitive data types are strings, numbers, booleans and, recently, [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)s

Comment: *"You can do that with non-primitive values, though"* No, you can't. "Pass by reference" is a specific term with a specific meaning: Passing a reference **to the variable** you're using when calling the function. (Which is, of course, a feature JavaScript doesn't have.) Passing an object reference is still pass by value (the value being the object reference).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Alright, you made a point. I just wrote that for the sake of simplicity, whereas it's more correct to say that non-primitive values are always referenced.

Comment: *Values* are never referenced in JavaScript; *objects* are referenced. Values are copied around -- between variables, when passing them into functions, coming out of functions, etc. One kind of value is a number. Another kind of value is an object reference. Objects are *not* values.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fine, let's say non-primitive data types then. I don't know how that would help the point, though.

Answer (score 0):

You only pass the value of this attribute to the function, so you don't change the style element, you only change the value, can do it in this way:

```
function doubleup(attr){
    return attr*=2;
}

myDIV.style.opacity = doubleup(myDIV.style.opacity);
myDIV.style.zIndex = doubleup(myDIV.style.zIndex);
```

By the way, you have to use `zIndex` instead of `z-index` to manipulate this value.

Another possible solution is:

```
function doubleup(el){
    el.style.opacity*=2;
}
function doubleupZIndex(el){
    el.style.zIndex*=2;
}

doubleupOpacity(myDIV);
doubleupZIndex(myDIV);
```